# Resizing a UIImage, or CIImage, before cropping, stretches the images?

Tags: ios, uiimage, resize, crop, core-image

OK, I've tried every single example I can find to do this, sadly most of them are from 2008-2009 and iOS5 seems to be very different.  I simply want to resize and image so that the short edge is a size I specify, and it stays in proportion.

I am using AVFoundation to grab an image from the camera, I convert that through a UIImage to a CIImage so I can apply filters and fiddle with it, before converting back to a UIImage for saving.

```
- (void) startCamera {

session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = _cameraView.bounds;
[_cameraView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
NSError *error = nil;

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    //no cam, handle error - need to put up a nice happy note here
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
}

[session addInput:input];

stillImage = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG , AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImage setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:stillImage];
[session startRunning];
}

- (IBAction) _cameraButtonPress:(id)sender {

AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImage.connections)
{
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
    {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
        {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) {
        break;
    }
}

[stillImage captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

    NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
    UIImage *startImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    //resizing of image to take place before anything else
    UIImage *image = [startImage imageScaledToFitSize:_exportSSize];  //resizes to the size given in the prefs

    //change the context to render using cpu, so on app exit renders get completed
    context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:
               [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                           forKey:kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer]];

    //set up the saving library
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    //create a new ciimage
    CIImage *greyImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];

    //create a CIMonochrome filter 
    desaturate = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, greyImage, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00], nil];

    //[crop setValue:ciImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    //[crop setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0f Y:0.0f Z:_exportSize W:_exportSize] forKey:@"inputRectangle"];

    CIImage *croppedColourImage = [desaturate valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    //convert it to a cgimage for saving
    CGImageRef cropColourImage = [context createCGImage:croppedColourImage fromRect:[croppedColourImage extent]];

     //saving of the images         
     [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:cropColourImage metadata:[croppedColourImage properties] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"ERROR in image save: %@", error);
     } else
     {
         NSLog(@"SUCCESS in image save");
         //in here we'll put a nice animation or something
         CGImageRelease(cropColourImage);
     }

     }];
}];
}
```

This code is test code so will have all sorts of attempts in it, apologies for that.

The closest I've got is using Matt Gemmell's code [here](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities)

But that, no matter what I try, always stretches the image.  I want to resize the image then crop it to be 512 pixels square.  If I just do a CICrop filter it takes the top left 512 pixels so I lose a lot of the image (grabbing a high res photo, as later I'll also want to export 1800x1800 images).  My thinking was to resize the image first, then crop.  But no matter what I do, the image gets stretched.

So my question is, is there a proper suggested recognised way to resize and image in iOS5+?

Thanks.

Comment: I have found one way to do it: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  Which may not be the way I'm supposed to, but it's working for now.  Wondering why Apple didn't make this easier! :)

Comment: I just ran into this exact same issue however the model you are suggesting didn't seem to work for me.  I posted the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491080/uiimage-resizing-not-working-properly

Comment: And I provided a solution that works for me in that other thread, too (which works fine in iOS 5): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491080/uiimage-resizing-not-working-properly/10491692#10491692

Comment: @Nick, so you use your keyboard as a test model too! :)  I wonder if all of us are doing that?  I'll check out your method after my Monday morning meetings...

Comment: @RobertRyan - I'm assuming - (UIImage*)scaleImageToSizeFill:(CGSize)newSize; will crop the image, - (UIImage*)scaleImageToSizeAspectFill:(CGSize)newSize; will resize but keep the aspect (resize to shortest length?) and - (UIImage*)scaleImageToSizeAspectFit:(CGSize)newSize; resizes the entire image so it fits within the new bounds?

Comment: @mrEmpty, yes, that's the intent, to honor the standard definitions of UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill and andUIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit as defined by [UIViewContentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW69). I hope my category works out for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found one way to do it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```