# Need to load "original" image in NSData without Compression

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The UIImageJPEGRepresentation not return the original image. It will return compressed value of an actual image. Need to load original image data set in NSData. Is there any way to read actual data from image?

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005456/calling-imagewithdatauiimagejpegrepresentation-multiple-times-only-compresses

Answer (score -2):

I think you have tried below code to using **UIImageJPEGRepresentation**

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

You can convert image to data like this and vice-versa like this.

**Convert UIImage to NSData (png) :**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

**Convert NSData to UIImage :**

```
NSData *data = ... // data that you received
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```