# UIImageView not showing transparency of PNG Images from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, png, uiimagepickercontroller

I surely hope I am missing something because I do not understand why this is working the way it does.  I have a PNG Image, which has a fully transparent background because I want to overlay it on other images inside a `UIImageView`.

PNG images included in the XCode project all work fine as they should.  The problem is when I select these same PNG images on the fly using `UIImagePickerController` and then assigning it to the `UIImageView`, for some really bizarre reason, it is not respecting it as a PNG Image with transparency and instead it adding a white background.

Anyone seen this before and how do I get around this?

*** UPDATE #1:** I decided to try something that seems to confirm my theory.  I decided to email myself the original PNG images I saved to my device and lo and behold, the images came to me as JPG.  Seems to me that when you save an image to Photos on iPhone it converts it to JPG, this is rather shocking to me. Hope someone has a way around this.  The original images `testImage1.png` and `testImage2.png` saved to Photos and then emailed back to myself, returned as `IMG_XXXX.jpg` and `IMG_XXXX.jpg`

*** UPDATE #2:** I kept playing around we this more and found out a few things and in the process was able to answer my own question.  (1) My theory in UPDATE #1 is partially correct, but the conversion does not happen when saving the Photo, seems like it is on the fly.  Internally photos stores the original image extension (2) I was able to validate this when I realized in my `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` that I was using

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
```

instead of this

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

When I used the second line of code, it was recognizing the original transparency properties for the image.

Comment: Just to make sure: did you set the backgroundColor of the UIImageView to clearColor?

Comment: Yes I did.  It's almost as if UIImagePickerController ignore transparency or it converts selected Images to JPG.  I'm using the same UIImageView for both scenarios and when I select the same Image via UIImagePickerController it adds a white background, when I select the image that was included as part of the XCode Project it works fine.

Comment: I just did something that seems to confirm my theory.  I decided to email myself the original PNG images I saved to my device and lo and behold, the images came to me as JPG.  Seems to me that when you save an image to Photos on iPhone it converts it to JPG

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the call to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` will convert the resulting image into a JPEG, which doesn't support transparency.

BTW, if your intent is to get the `NSData` for the image for other reasons (e.g. uploading to server, emailing, etc.), I would recommend against both `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. They lose meta data, can make the asset larger, if suffer some image degradation if you use quality factor of less than 1, etc.

Instead, I'd recommend going back and get the original asset from the Photos framework. Thus, in Swift 3:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url], options: nil)
        if let asset = result.firstObject {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { imageData, dataUTI, orientation, info in
                if let fileURL = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? URL {
                    let filename = fileURL.lastPathComponent
                    // use filename here
                }

                // use imageData here
            }
        }
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

If you have to support iOS 7, too, you'd use the equivalent `ALAssetsLibrary` API, but the idea is the same: Get the original asset rather than round-tripping it through a `UIImage`.

(For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32938728/1).)

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to finally re-visit this and get the code working.  This is exactly what I needed, to get the original photos asset.

Comment: if one were to use this approach, would there be anyway to resize the image or further reducing the size before uploading to server?  thx

Comment: The intent of this approach is to get the original asset with no quality loss, and not suffering the enlarging of the file that can take place if you use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with quality of 1.0. If you need it even smaller, go ahead and get the `UIImage` of the default representation, and then apply resize function (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28513086/1271826) and then use `UIImagePNG/JPEGRepresentation`. If you do resize, resizing it by a power of 2 will offer dramatically smaller images without softening them.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of answer by @Rob

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
        let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [URL as URL], options: nil)
        if let asset:PHAsset = result.firstObject! as PHAsset {
            let manager = PHImageManager.default()
            manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { imageData, dataUTI, orientation, info in
                let fileURL = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as? NSURL
                let filename = fileURL?.lastPathComponent;

                // use imageData here
            }
        }
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution uses the PHAssetResourceManager rather than PHImageManager. Using Xcode 10, Swift 4.2.

```
func imageFromResourceData(phAsset:PHAsset) {

    let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: phAsset)

    for resource in assetResources {

        if resource.type == PHAssetResourceType.photo {

            var imageData = Data()

            let options = PHAssetResourceRequestOptions()
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

            let _ = PHAssetResourceManager.default().requestData(for: resource, options: options, dataReceivedHandler: { (data:Data) in
                imageData.append(data)
            }, completionHandler: { (error:Error?) in
                if error == nil, let picked = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    self.handlePickedImage(picked: picked)
                }
            })
        }

    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    dismiss(animated: true)

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as! NSString

    if mediaType == kUTTypeImage || mediaType == kUTTypeLivePhoto {

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

            if let phAsset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
                self.imageFromResourceData(phAsset: phAsset)
            }
            else {
                if let picked = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage) {
                    self.handlePickedImage(picked: picked)
                }
            }

        }
        else if let picked = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage) {
            self.handlePickedImage(picked: picked)
        }
    }
}
```