# change an UI Image into a String array

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift3, rgba

I have an UIImage made of only 4 types of pixel.

```
static let black = RGBA32(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
static let red   = RGBA32(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
static let green = RGBA32(red: 0, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 255)
static let blue  = RGBA32(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 255, alpha: 255)
```

( reference to the code used to create the Image https://stackoverflow.com/a/40207142/7010252 )

I saved the image in the phone's photo library then I open the image in my app again. I know that the number of pixel is the same.

So how can I get the RGBA data of all the pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing done here is to loop through your image and create a map of all the points in it.

```
func getPixelColor(image: UIImage) {
    let width = image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height

    for x in 0..<Int(width) {
        for y in 0..<Int(height) {
            let color = image.pixelColor(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y)))
            print(color.RGBA)
        }
    }
}
```

Once it has the color it wants, it then calls the `RGBA` function in the `UIColor` extension to provide the string you want.

Next, we use an extension of `UIImage` to then take the points provided by the above function and query the image data for its `UIColor` data.

```
extension UIImage {
    func pixelColor(_ point: CGPoint) -> UIColor {
        let pixelData = cgImage?.dataProvider?.data
        let pointerData: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

        let pixelInfo = Int(((self.size.width * point.y) + point.x)) * 4

        let maxValue: CGFloat = 255.0
        let compare: CGFloat = 0.99

        let r: CGFloat = (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo]) / maxValue) > compare ? 1.0 : 0.0
        let g: CGFloat = (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo + 1]) / maxValue) > compare ? 1.0 : 0.0
        let b: CGFloat = (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo + 2]) / maxValue) > compare ? 1.0 : 0.0
        let a = CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo + 3]) / maxValue

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

This extension uses the raw data to determine the RGB values of each pixel. It then performs a crude check to play safe with CGFloats to see if the value is 255.0 for that particular color. If it is, it will return a value of 1.0, otherwise it returns 0.0.

Next, there is an extension for UIColor that will provide the formatted string you are looking for.

```
extension UIColor {
    var RGBA: String {
        guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count == 4 else {
            return ""
        }

        return "\(components[0])-\(components[1])-\(components[2])-\(components[3])"
    }
}
```

This should provide the 1-0-0-1 type of values you seek. You can also modify this to include any additional information you need.

Comment: but when I use that code there is a problem.
I should get either (rgba)

1-0-0-1 (red) / 0-1-0-1 (green) / 0-0-1-1 (blue) / 0-0-0-1 (black)

but I get double such as : (rgba) 0.6787878 - 0.823345 - 0.34522 - 1

Comment: Updated to address your issue. Hopefully that resolves it.

Comment: nope didn't work, I always get "0.0-0.0-0.0-1.0". It means the pixel is black but actually the picture isn't black. Do you have any Idea how I need to fix it ? @CodeBender

Comment: it isn't : let r: CGFloat = (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo]) / maxValue) > 254.9 ? 1.0 : 0.0

Comment: it is : let r: CGFloat = (CGFloat(pointerData[pixelInfo]) / maxValue) > 0.9 ? 1.0 : 0.0

Comment: My bad, I just checked it too late. Updated answer to include that.