# Why base64 renditions of images are white in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage, base64, image-uploading

I have converted my images with this codes below and this will return base64 of my images but the problem is that when I upload them into the server I just see the white image - can you suggest me the better way to convert images to base64 or this is the best way that I choose 
here is the converting image to base64

```
 func base64(from image: UIImage) -> String? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)
    if let imageString = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed) {
        return imageString
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: one thing you can do is construct the image back from the base64 string which is generated , if that works check compress the image and check whether the string is properly sent, since base64 string size is too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is white because nothing is drawn on current context !!!

You are just `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` with size

and get with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`

it will always gives you a white image and there is no relation with Base64

If you want to render something  then use like below

```
        yourImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

and after that fetch image from currentContext

**EDIT**

```
func base64(from image: UIImage) -> String? { 
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size) 
   image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)) 
   let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() 
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext() 
   let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0) 
   if let imageString = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed) { 
   return imageString 
   } 
    return nil 
  }
```

Comment: the swift says value of UIImage has no member layer

Comment: This is not UIImage it should be UIImageView

Comment: I have an array of UIImage not image view

Comment: And you want  to combine all images to one ?

Comment: You have to use image.draw Method

Comment: no I have an UIImage array and want to convert them into base64 array and upload this array

Comment: not working again the swift doesn't let me to run the app see below this answer is working but just for first image

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Check Now, I don't understand why you are using context to draw ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150561/discussion-between-saeed-rahmatolahi-and-mike-alter).

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:

```
func convertImageToBase64(_ image:UIImage) -> String
  {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)//get imageData from image
    if(imageData != nil)
    {
      let Strbase64 = imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithCarriageReturn)//encode imageData
      return Strbase64!//return encoded string
    }
    return ""
  }
```

Comment: this code will work but when I upload two image in the server just first image is exist second image is in the server but it is 0 kb

Comment: i think you need some delay after convert into base64 and then convert second image

Comment: No, you don't need any delay when converting into base64. This problem about the second image being empty image is likely something completely unrelated.

Comment: no I have taken these images from camera of the iPhone - I don't need to wait too because I want to upload them quickly

Comment: if my answer is realy helpful to you then accept it so other can get help from it.

Answer (score 1):

You passed a `UIImage` to this method, but never did anything with it, but rather created a new `UIImage` using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, but you never drew anything to that context. That's why the resulting images are white.

But you don't need those `UIGraphics` calls at all. Just grab the JPEG representation of the `UIImage` that you passed into this method, and convert it to a base 64 encoded string:

```
func convertImageToBase64(_ image: UIImage) -> String? {
    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)?.base64EncodedString()
}
```

Comment: This is not working look up the answer is working but not for more than one image

Comment: Like I said in my comment to the other question, the problem with multiple images is not this conversion to base64. The above is how you do that conversion and there's not much to it. The multiple image problem is either how you're grabbing these multiple `UIImage` references or how you're saving them or something like that. But you haven't provided enough in your question to help us diagnose this secondary, multiple image problem.

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi - By the way, in comments to another answer, you said you're taking pictures from the phone. If using `UIImagePickerController`, for example, it's inefficient to grab the `UIImage` objects, convert them to `Data`/`NSData` and then doing the base 64 conversion. You generally would want to grab the original `Data`/`NSData` asset (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938728/1271826). But without more context, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

First check wether the error you are facing is from your app or server side .You can choose online base64 to image converter .Copy your base64 String and check them first , you can choose this link

https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter