# How to resize an image in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimage

hi I want to send an image to a web service. But I want to resize user selected any image into 75 x 75 and send it to web service. How can I resize this image into 75 x 75

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491080/uiimage-resizing-not-working-properly/10491692#10491692 check this awesome Answer by Rob

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try to implement the code below. It may be helpful for you:

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,75,75);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
    [yourCurrentOriginalImage drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: hi thanks for thr rply,, If I send in JPG format, how to change this `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

Comment: you can use UIImageJPEGRepresentation , it needs the quality in float.

Comment: Why do did you add the extra step where you create PNG data only to create a new image again?

Comment: yes you are right but i think at that time he asking me to chagne quolity about i am not remember well but might be for that i added it other wise picture1 is good to go.

Comment: Thanks @NitinGohel for your superb solution.

Answer (score 33):

Use this method to resize your image:

```
+(UIImage *)imageResize :(UIImage*)img andResizeTo:(CGSize)newSize
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    /*You can remove the below comment if you dont want to scale the image in retina   device .Dont forget to comment UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions*/
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, scale);
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

try this code:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```