# iPhone UIWebView photo upload memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiwebview

Whenever I upload a image using `webView` in iOS I got some memory leak

```
malloc 16byte  JavascriptCore                      only one time
PhotoLibrary 144byte CAMBulleredSnapShotView       multiple time
CALayer      48byte    UIKit                       multiple time
UIStatusBarHideAnimationParameters 48byte          multiple time
malloc     144&16 byte     Quartzcore              multiple time
```

how I release it any help thanks in advance

Comment: what is the size if your image ??

Comment: i direct click image from iPhone5 cam

Comment: I think you need to resize the image. then display the image in Webview 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018617/how-to-resize-an-image-in-ios

Comment: @bhupesh i use HTML5 upload image from <input type='file'>  not any code in webview