# How to get AVCaptureStillImageOutput same aspect ratio as the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation

I'm capturing an image using `AVFoundation`. I'm using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to display the camera feed on screen. This preview layer's frame gets the bounds of a `UIView` with dynamic dimensions:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
CALayer *rootLayer = [self.cameraFeedView layer];
[rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
CGRect frame = self.cameraFeedView.frame;
[previewLayer setFrame:frame];
previewLayer.frame = rootLayer.bounds;
[rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];
```

And I'm using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to capture an image:

```
AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                              completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
                                                      NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
                                                      UIImage *capturedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                                                  }
                                              }];
```

My problem is that the captured image is at the size of the iPhone camera (1280x960 - front camera), but I need it to be the same aspect ratio as the preview layer. For example, if the size of the preview layer is 150x100, I need the captured image to be 960x640. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Try to resize the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018617/how-to-resize-an-image-in-ios

Comment: I tried resizing already, but because the aspect ratio is different, the resized image looks squished. I can crop the image, but isn't there a way to just get the original frame from the preview layer?

Answer (score 1):

I also enter counter the same problem. You have to crop or resize output still image. But you should notice that output still`s scale and image orientation.

preview layer square frame

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds);
[self.captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width)];
[self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:self.captureVideoPreviewLayer];
```

calculate cropped image`s frame

```
[self.captureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:captureConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
    NSData *data = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake((image.size.height - image.size.width) / 2, 0, image.size.width, image.size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:image.scale orientation:image.imageOrientation]; // always UIImageOrientationRight
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}];
```