# How to set same size images in tableviewcell?

Tags: ios

[image: Image 1]

I need the images in my table to be the same size, such as 40x40 or 30x40. How can I do this?

Comment: please go throught these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018617/how-to-resize-an-image-in-ios

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658738/the-simplest-way-to-resize-an-uiimage

If you are not using Autolayout then please read autolayout & set in your code. 
You are a beginner so please try to put some code or work you have done in order to avoid vote-down. Do some google.

Comment: make the image view **Aspect fill** and clips to bounds enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Give the height and width constraint to imageView and then make the clip to bounds property of imageView to true.