# How to reduce the image size coming from web services?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In the below shown image i am getting the images from web services and passing it to a table view but when scrolling up and down the image size was increasing and it is overlapping on labels and i had given constraints also can anyone help me how to avoid this ?

[image]

Comment: resize your image before load

Comment: how to resize the image ? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018617/how-to-resize-an-image-in-ios. check this for resize the image.

Comment: can anyone post the answer for swift it is in objective c @VishalKalola

Comment: https://objectivec2swift.com/ convert code into swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had placed a view on table view cell and then I had placed all the elements and given constraints for view and elements in it then my problem has been reduced and working perfectly when scrolling also and is as shown in image below.

here is the layout for this screen

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hey you don't need to resize image.

1. First Set fix height width of your image view with constraints in tableview cell
2. Second Set imageview to aspectFit.

   ```
   imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
   ```
3. Constraints add like this of your image view

[image: Image View Constraints]

Hope you will get success using that, if you any query regarding this , just comment will help

Comment: before itself i had given the height constraint but when i given image view aspect fit also still problem continues just see my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ioV.png

Comment: @VamsiKrishna .. Please also set fix width of your imageview , Because its still have auto resizing in width part. So please fix width

Comment: Please try once more .. Remove all cell contraint and set your image view constraints first and after set other constraints

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/onYm4.png these r my constraints for image view

Comment: Don't set trailing space.. Its mistake .. Constraints are over loop. Please see Image that i have attached in answer

Comment: that trailing for my beside elements i.e is labels and button should i need not to give or not  ?

Answer (score 0):

Using content mode to fit the image is an option but if you want to crop or resize it or compress image check the below code.

Call like `let imageData = image.compressImage(rate: 0.5)` and then you can provide data to write the image if needed.

```
func compressImage(rate: CGFloat) -> Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, rate)
    }
```

OR If you want to crop the image then,

```
func croppedImage(_ bound: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        guard self.size.width > bound.origin.x else {
            print("X coordinate is larger than the image width")
            return nil
        }
        guard self.size.height > bound.origin.y else {
            print("Y coordinate is larger than the image height")
            return nil
        }
        let scaledBounds: CGRect = CGRect(x: bound.x * self.scale, y: bound.y * self.scale, width: bound.w * self.scale, height: bound.h * self.scale)
        let imageRef = self.cgImage?.cropping(to: scaledBounds)
        let croppedImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: UIImageOrientation.up)
        return croppedImage
    }
```

Make sure to add the above methods to UIImage Extension.