# When using UIImageJPEGRepresentation what number retains full resolution?

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

Can someone please explain the scale for me (0 to 1)? Which is the best quality/least, and how does that affect file size?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17475842/1271826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About scale

> The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best quality).

Comment: But 1.0 is rarely the best choice, it is usual to drop back a little, it is a  compromise of quality to file size.

Comment: Or use PNG which offers lossless compression (and preserves transparencies). Or, even better, where possible, go back to the original asset used for creating the image (e.g. the `NSData` used with `imageWithData`, or if you retrieved it from photos/assets library, there is API to retrieve the original asset). Clearly, if you dynamically created image with `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext`, then you have to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, but otherwise you're generally better served going back to original asset.